# Change tabcontroller index

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a list of tiles that each represent a category for the next page `TabBarView`.

the list tiles are derived from a model which has 2 parameters `imageUrl` and `title`

When the user taps the tile, I want them to be redirected to another view that has `TabBar` and `TabBarView` and I want the view to be focused on the specific category tapped by the user before. I want to translate the index of the list tile to be change the `TabController` index

here is my current solution but I failed to change the controller index value

```dart
final List<MHSpecialty> specialty = [
      MHSpecialty(imageUrl: "assets/icon/doctor.png",specialtyName:'doctor'),
      MHSpecialty(imageUrl: "assets/icon/nurse.png",specialtyName: 'nurse'),
      MHSpecialty(imageUrl: "assets/icon/engineer.png", specialtyName: 'engineer'),
      MHSpecialty(imageUrl: "assets/icon/teacher.png", specialtyName: 'teacher'),
  ];
```

i am using GetX

```dart
Widget _getListWidget( specialty ){
      return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children :specialty.map<Widget>((i) => GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                      mHController.specialtyTabController.index = int.parse(specialty[i]);
                      Get.to(BrowseBySpecialty());
                  },
                  child: SpecialtyTile(
                         specialtyImage: i.imageUrl,
                         specialtyName: i.specialtyName),
          )).toList()
      );
  }
```

Comment: could you share code of the target screen? The one where `TabController` is

Comment: Are you using `mHController.specialtyTabController` as TabController on the other screen?